# How to close modal view controller in monotouch

Tags: xcode, ipad, xamarin.ios

I have used storyboard to design UI in monotouch. I have button which once you click on it
it will use PerformSegue to move to another view controller the segue works as modal so It will pop up a form.

My problem is I have included cancel `barbuttonitem` in navigation bar but I cannot dismiss or close this modal.

Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add delegate on your button and dissmiss your modal view in this delegate:

```
yourButton.Clicked += (sender, e) => {
        this.DismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true);
});
```

And for pushin views, I use this:

```
this.NavigationController.PushViewController (
        yourView, true
);
```

I hope that helped.